# Lack of symmetry in Poynting vector

Tags: electromagnetism

I've noticed that there's a lack of symmetry in the definition of the Poynting vector, being defined as:
$$S=E\times H$$
meaning, using the electric field cross the magnetizing field instead of the displacement field cross the magnetizing field ($S=D\times H$).

Why is that?

Comment: Do you know how to "derive" the Poynting vector (*i.e.* the motivation for it as an energy flux in a continuity equation for energy flows)? If not, check out Feynman Lectures, Vol 2 Ch27 http://www.feynmanlectures.caltech.edu/II_27.html and you'll see that it is $E\times H$ (or $\epsilon_0\,c^2\,E\times B$, as Feynman derives it) that is the pertinent quantity.

Comment: I'm familiar with the derivation, what I ask for is a more "intuitive" explanation as for the reason why.

Comment: When you say "lack of symmetry", what relationship are you thinking of that suggests $D\times H$? There's the very basic reason that $D\times H$ has the wrong dimensions to be an intensity (power flux density). Also, the derivation, especially as Feynman gives it, shows you that this is quite a subtle thing: you're looking for something that, with Maxwell's equations, will give you a continuity equation and postulating $S$ as something - not needfully the unique thing - which can do this.